# Python converting query output

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python script that has a SQL query returned into a list of lists, e.g.:

```py
result = [ ['12345', 'Red', 'House', 150, '18/05/2016', 27.3],
           ['34534', 'Blue', 'Car', 500, '22/12/2015', 587.52] ]
```

The first item in each list is the ID, then each item is an attribute related to each record, such as `Colour`, `Type`, `Size`, `Date`, `Cost`.

The item attributes like `Colour`, `Date` etc. are potentially different for every SQL query run, as these are dynamically added to my SQL query from another query result (which queries columns) e.g.:

```py
columns = {'RecID': 'RecordID', 'Color': 'Colour', 'Type': 'Type', 'Size': 'Size', 'PurchaseDate': 'Date', 'PurchaseCost': 'Cost'}

newQueryFields = "[UniqueID]"
for x in columns:
    newQueryFields = "{}, [{}]".format(newQueryFields, columns[x])
```

I've managed to get it into a dictionary of lists using the following code, but for the (yet unwritten) rest of the code, it would be better if I could refer to dictionary items.

```py
newResult = dict()
for rec in result:
    newResult[rec[0]] = rec
```

Which results in:

```py
result = {'12345': ['12345', 'Red', 'House', 150, '18/05/2016', 27.3],
          '34534': ['34534', 'Blue', 'Car', 500, '22/12/2015', 587.52] }
```

However I'm trying to get the results into a dictionary of dictionaries ( I think? ) but I can't get my head around how to structure my code to output:

```py
newResult = {'12345': {'ID': '12345', 'Colour': 'Red', 'Type': 'House', 'Size': 150, 'Date': '18/05/2016', 'Cost': 27.3}, 
             '34534': {'ID': '34534', 'Colour': 'Blue', 'Type': 'Car', 'Size': 500, 'Date': '22/12/2015', 'Cost': 587.52} }
```

Comment: Is the order of field always same?

Comment: The result of the query will always output the fields in the order they're queried.  Field order isn't an issue, but as the field names are dynamic they could be any field in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to give you an idea about what you could do if you had the `columns` already with you:

```
columns = ['ID', 'Colour', 'Type', 'Size', 'Date', 'Cost']
newResult = {rec[0]: dict(zip(columns, rec)) for rec in result}
```

Obviously, you need to get the `columns` first which are added dynamically in your case.

Comment: So if I can get my columns into a list I should be able to pass that into newResult as the result should be in the same order.  Thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: thanks AKS that's exactly what I needed.  Appreciated.